# How to view dbase tables?

Tags: qgis, dbf

Using Linux, is there something out there to quickly view a dbase file? Sometimes there are look-up tables(.dbf) to accompany a shapefile. Libre Office Calc can't read it. Maybe a QGIS plugin that can read and or join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qgis can open dbf format. Just use the Add vector layer and change the format to dBASE.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) it can also read/write .dbf files.